# Set image links to be refreshed every 0.5 seconds from the values defined in the text bars

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I would like `AAAAAAAAAA`, `BBBBBBBBBB` and `CCCCCCCCCC` to be defined from the links that I put in the **text bars** named `chart1`, `chart2` and `chart3`, what is the best and simplest way to define it this way?

> This project is for learning and I'm doing it through Notepad++, for
> private use, without the need to save data for future use. Every time
> I open the HTML, the links I'll put in the bars will be different.

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = 'AAAAAAAAAA';
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = 'BBBBBBBBBB';
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = 'CCCCCCCCCC';
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">

</body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<p></p>
<iframe src="XXXXXXXXXX" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="YYYYYYYYYY" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="ZZZZZZZZZZ" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="AAAAAAAAAA" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="BBBBBBBBBB" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="CCCCCCCCCC" name="Gráfico3">

</html>
```

Script updated from statement made in response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355982/11462274)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `refreshIt` properly. You are passing a string instead of a function as a parameter.

Instead, use:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = 'AAAAAAAAAA';
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = 'BBBBBBBBBB';
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = 'CCCCCCCCCC';
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">

</body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<p></p>
<iframe src="XXXXXXXXXX" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="YYYYYYYYYY" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="ZZZZZZZZZZ" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="AAAAAAAAAA" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="BBBBBBBBBB" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="CCCCCCCCCC" name="Gráfico3">

</html>
```

To set the source to the value from the text bars, get the `value` property of the inputs:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = chart1.value;
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = chart2.value;
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = chart3.value;
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">

</body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<p></p>
<iframe src="XXXXXXXXXX" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="YYYYYYYYYY" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe src="ZZZZZZZZZZ" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="AAAAAAAAAA" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="BBBBBBBBBB" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="CCCCCCCCCC" name="Gráfico3">

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I have already modified it according to your indication. Could you also help me how to set the values from the text bars?

Comment: @BrondbyIF No problem - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the teachings you shared with me in your response!